# How to calculate max(column) row from a result set grouped by different items

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT T1.* FROM 
(
    SELECT
        MAX(no_of_orders)   [no_of_orders], 
        ord.customer_id     [customer_id], 
        ord_dtl.item_id     [item_id]
    FROM order_main ord
    INNER JOIN order_detail ord_dtl
        ON ord.order_id = ord_dtl.order_id      
    GROUP BY 
        ord.customer_id, ord_dtl.item_id
) T1    
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        MAX(no_of_orders) [no_of_orders], 
        ord.customer_id
    FROM order_main ord
    INNER JOIN order_detail ord_dtl
        ON ord.order_id = ord_dtl.order_id
    GROUP BY 
        ord.customer_id
) T2
ON 
    T1.customer_id = T2.customer_id
    AND T1.no_of_orders = T2.no_of_orders
```

I calculated the most ordered item by customer from table order_main and order_detail.

What I did is like I calculated the no of orders grouping by customer id and item id and to reduce the result set to most ordered item by customer, I joined the resultset by same query removing the grouping by item id.

I don't feel this is a good query.

Any better alternative ?

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36fd6/1)

Comment: Cannot understand what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most ordered item by customer

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36fd6/5)**

```
SELECT a.no_of_orders,
       a.customer_id,
       a.item_id
FROM (SELECT
        MAX(no_of_orders)   [no_of_orders], 
        ord.customer_id     [customer_id], 
        ord_dtl.item_id     [item_id],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ord.customer_id  ORDER BY MAX(no_of_orders) DESC) AS rnk
    FROM order_main ord
    INNER JOIN order_detail ord_dtl
        ON ord.order_id = ord_dtl.order_id      
    GROUP BY 
        ord.customer_id, ord_dtl.item_id) a
WHERE a.rnk = 1
```

Result:

```
| NO_OF_ORDERS | CUSTOMER_ID | ITEM_ID |
---------------|-------------|---------|
|           20 |           2 |       6 |
|           50 |           7 |       6 |
|         1500 |           8 |       7 |
|           10 |           9 |       3 |
```